# Postgres database takes time to get total record count

Tags: postgresql

I am using **Postgres database** and I had a **daily_txns** table which contains more then 2,00,00,000 records in it, 
so I have created child table partitions inheriting the master transaction  table as **daily_txns_child_2017_08_01**  for daily transaction.
I am searching for a `indexed column **mid**  and **created_date**` it takes longer time to respond, even for getting the total records in it takes longer time.
How to speed up the data fetch? It takes me more then **5 min for first query and for second query it takes more then 20 min.**
My Query are as below.

```
select * from daily_txns where created_date <='2017-08-01' and created_date>='2017-07-01' and mid='0446721M0008690' order by created_date desc limit 10;

select count(mid) from daily_txns where created_date <='2017-08-01' and created_date>='2017-07-01' and mid='0446721M0008690';
```

Or the time taken is a normal one.

Comment: Have you added indexes to the table? Indexing `created_date` and `mid` columns will massively increase the query performance.

Comment: yes I have added index for created date and mid

Comment: what is the exact check constraint you use for partitioning?..

Comment: CREATE TABLE ".$nextTable." (
                                CONSTRAINT pk_".$_nextDate." PRIMARY KEY (id),
                                            CONSTRAINT ck_".$_nextDate." CHECK ( created_date >= DATE '$nextDate' AND created_date < DATE '$next2Date' )
                                    ) INHERITS (daily_txns)

Comment: Generally speaking postgresql will need to sequentially scan a table to get an accurate count because visibility doesn't exist in indexes for this. HOWEVER, later versions can do index only scans. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-index-only-scans.html to see if your indexes an meet the requirement for index only scans. 

Note that pgsql still has to trundle through the whole index, but it's faster than seqscanning the table.